# How to select route lines that fall outside ZIP boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, route, zip-codes

I have two tables. One of route lines, with associated Zip Codes, and another of Zip Code boundaries. Some of the lines cross over their Zip boundaries. Below is zoomed in picture demonstrating my problem.

[image]

The areas circled in gray are where I would have to go in and change the boundaries to encompass the route. They are color coded by Zip Code.

Is there a select by attributes solution to this, that would show me which lines are outside of their respective zones?

I am using ArcMap 10.2, Thanks for any possible help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do this would be to create a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) operation where you join the Zip Code polygons (which should have a zip attribute) to the lines (which have a similar zip attribute).  Then you could just query the lines where `lines_zip <> polys_zip`.  Once you were done, you could then use [Delete Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004n000000) to drop the polygon fields you no longer need.

Depending on your use case, you could even create a simple [ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000001000000) tool that would automate this process for you, if you needed to repeat it regularly.